# CMake won't find_path in yocto environment, but will with same repo and cmake outside of yocto

Tags: cmake, yocto

I am having trouble getting a recipe build in Yocto.

The only thing you need to know if that Yocto setups up sysroots and other environment variables for builds (PKG_CONFIG_PATH, PATH, compiler flags, etc).

[Here](https://pastebin.com/s2G2aaEi) is the output of `printenv` used during the Yocto build. Something in here is causing `find_path` to fail in CMake.

Here is the bit that is failing.

```
find_path( MFX_INCLUDE mfxdefs.h PATHS ${MFX_API_HOME}/include )
```

In the cross environment, `MFX_INCLUDE` gets set to `MFX_INCLUDE-NOTFOUND`. In my local non-cross environment, it (correctly) get's set to `/home/pknopf/git/MediaSDK/api/include` because it correctly finds the `mfxdefs.h` in there.

Any ideas as to why my `find_path` command would be calling on one, and not the other?

By the way, my local machine is using CMake 3.5.1 (working), while Yocto is using 3.7.2 (not working).

I feel it has something to do with the environment variables setup by Yocto, but I'm not sure which one.

**EDIT**: To make things a little more clear, the following is not working.

```
find_path( MFX_INCLUDE mfxdefs.h PATHS /home/pknopf/git/x3/abrarecipes/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/msdk/git-r0/git/api/include)
```

This results in:

```
MFX_INCLUDE-NOTFOUND
```

Here is the contents of `/home/pknopf/git/x3/abrarecipes/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/msdk/git-r0/git/api/include`:

```
ls -l /home/pknopf/git/x3/abrarecipes/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/msdk/git-r0/git/api/include
total 220
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  4320 Mar  2 15:24 mfxastructures.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2979 Mar  2 15:24 mfxaudio.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  4966 Mar  2 15:24 mfxaudio++.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  4639 Mar  2 16:03 mfxbrc.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  4876 Mar  2 15:24 mfxcommon.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  6596 Mar  2 16:03 mfxdefs.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  7433 Mar  2 15:24 mfxdispatcherprefixedfunctions.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2477 Mar  2 15:24 mfxenc.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 15517 Mar  2 15:24 mfxfei.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  6529 Mar  2 16:03 mfxfeihevc.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2519 Mar  2 15:24 mfxjpeg.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2604 Mar  2 15:24 mfxla.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2533 Mar  2 15:24 mfxmvc.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2540 Mar  2 15:24 mfxpak.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 11116 Mar  2 16:03 mfxplugin.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 28017 Mar  2 15:24 mfxplugin++.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2136 Mar  2 15:24 mfxsession.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 50908 Mar  2 16:03 mfxstructures.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  5768 Mar  2 15:24 mfxvideo.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 10110 Mar  2 15:24 mfxvideo++.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  2175 Mar  2 15:24 mfxvp8.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000  1147 Mar  2 15:24 mfxvstructures.h
```

As you can see, `mfxdefs.h` is definitely there...

**EDIT2**: Using `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` fixed it. Not sure why, looking at documentation now.

Comment: Nice char with yourself :) Actually, when cross-compile *PATH* option is automatically prepended by sysroot in some cases. Set in the toolchain, variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE.html) controls that behavior globally.

Comment: It looks like Yocto is setting ```CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH``` to narrow the directories that CMake can search, preventing the cross-compile builds from picking up libraries on your native host. I am trying to append the ```MFX_INCLUDE``` to ```CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH```, hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: If directory `MFX_INCLUDE` contains files *suitable for the target*, then adding it to *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* is a good way. But if you want to find files which are suited for the host and not for the target, it is preferred to adjust specific `find_path` call (option `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` is nice for that purpose). Some toolchains define `find_host_path` macro, which searches files specifically for the host.